# Gradle error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/hash/HashUtil

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am getting the below error when I try to execute the command : **gradle clean build** on my system.

```
PS C:\Users\my-spring-boot-project> gradle clean build --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\my-spring-boot-project\settings.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'connectedhome-decision-support-tool-backend'.
> org/gradle/internal/hash/HashUtil

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'my-spring-boot-project'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
....
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/hash/HashUtil
        at org.kordamp.gradle.util.Cache$Key.<init>(Cache.groovy:42)
        at org.kordamp.gradle.util.Cache$Key.<init>(Cache.groovy)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

**settings.gradle is:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url = "${artifactory_url}/${artifactory_repoKey}"
            credentials {
                username  "${artifactory_username}"
                password  "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.my-company.gradle:parentbuild-spring-boot:1.1.90'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.my-company.gradle.parentbuild.spring-boot' ----------------> Line 16, Error on this line

rootProject.name = 'my-spring-boot-project'
```

**My versions are:**

java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS

Gradle 7.3.3

Incase it matters: IntellIJ version is IntellIJ IDEA 2021.2.3

I am very new to Gradle. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's coming from https://github.com/kordamp/kordamp-gradle-plugins/blob/master/plugins/base-gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/kordamp/gradle/util/Cache.groovy

This commit removes the reference for later versions of Gradle:

https://github.com/kordamp/kordamp-gradle-plugins/commit/b53171c9ecc61c40479e9d9044d4419b785bdc3e#diff-fe302b433f2713f6834e849752ebfbf8f326e6bf79385448e11bb34bfa5dd253L23

And the documentation is here https://kordamp.org/kordamp-gradle-plugins/

Check your build for `kordamp`:

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'org.kordamp.gradle:settings-gradle-plugin:0.45.0'
  classpath "org.kordamp.gradle:java-project-gradle-plugin:0.45.0"
}
```

And make sure it has `0.46.0` or later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

After referring to this https://github.com/kordamp/kordamp-gradle-plugins/issues/489, I updated the `gradle-wrapper.properties` to use the compatible version `(6.9.1)` of gradle for Java 11 which fixed the issue.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-bin.zip
```